# Add new Items to customviews tree

Tags: php, pimcore, pimcore-v5

I want to add new items under the H5P>home

**Existing tree is**

```
Documents -> Assets -> Data Objects -> H5P -> Home -> 
 - H5P.ArithmeticQuiz
 - H5P.InteractiveVideo
```

**What I want to do is**
Documents -> Assets ->
Data Objects -> H5P -> Home ->

- List
- New

Please check the screenshot for details: https://prnt.sc/uuqbbl

I will be very thankful for your valuable help.

Comment: This is not possible and it also does not make sense. All you want to do can be done via right mouse click within the Pimcore admin interface. Changing the Admin Interface is not a trivial task and you would have to fork Pimcore.